# Auto size property of Form in VB6

Tags: c#, vb6

Is there any auto re-size property of form in vb6 with respect to the control size ?

like `this.Auto Size = false` in c# ?

Comment: No, sizing and anchoring needs manually calculating I'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be interpreted in more than one way.

If you are asking if controls can be set to automatically resize in VB6 forms then the answer is no, resizing controls when the form resizes has to be done in code. It's not that hard if you're careful about how you design the form.

If you are asking if there is a way to set whether or not a form can be resized then you can use the BorderStyle property of the form, there are various options depending on what you want.